# Magento 2 : checkout_cart_index.xml problem

Tags: magento2, layout

When I copy `checkout_cart_index.xml` page to my theme it works fine but when I change

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/form.phtml" after="cart.summary">
```

to

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="Magento_Theme::cart/form.phtml" after="cart.summary">
```

For overriding a template file from my theme the discount coupon form disappears and it also disappears from from html too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: only phtml file override as your theme path folder not to xml file need to override.

Comment: If I do not override XML theme path it get template from module_checkout rather than my custom_theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I do is move checkout.cart.coupon to my container and it is was apparent where I want. Here is the code

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="summary-col1" before="-"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the the .phtml template file try to put your `form.phtml` file inside

> app/design/frontend/YourVendorThemeName/YourAciveThemeName/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

You should use `setTemplate` action in layout xml file, if you want to override phtml from your custom module

**checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>        
          <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::cart/form.phtml</argument>
             </action>
          </referenceBlock>
       </body>
    </page>
```